# Как изменить цвет строки treeview в зависимости от ее содержания?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-3.8

Возможно ли как-то изменить строки Treeview в Tkinter в зависимости от их содержания? Например: если в строке записано "оплачено", строка становится зелёная, если "неоплачено" - красная. Если что данные берутся из БД SQLite автоматически.

---

### Код

```
    conn = sqlite3.connect(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))+"/LC.db")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    #Вывовд всех учеников
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM STUD")
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    for row in rows:
        lvl1 = self.table.insert("" , tk.END , values=row)
        row1 = row[0],row[1],row[5]
        cur.execute('SELECT BOOK, AUT, STAT FROM LC WHERE FIO=(?) and DB=(?) AND PHONE = (?)',row1)
        books = cur.fetchall()
        for book in books:
            self.table.insert(lvl1, 'end',text='Книга',values=book)
```

**На этот вопрос есть один ответ, но к сожалению он не работает на Python 3.8.x в Windows10(работаю только на ней), потому объявлен конкурс. Ответ будет принят только тот, который будет работать на этой версии Python на Windows10!**

Comment: Вы писали багрепорт на bugs.python.org? Каков результат?

Comment: И второе - какие средства специфичные для Python 3.8 (которых нет в Python 3.6) вы используете у себя в коде?

Comment: @insolor, их сайт ни с одного моего устройства не открывается. Даже VPN пробовал

Comment: .@insolor, честно сам не знаю. Я только в python 3.8 работал. Это надо в интернете искать

Comment: у меня открывается с помощью расширения friGate, но нужно добавить сайт в список, в настройках.

Comment: Хорошие новости, похоже уже был такой баг-репорт, и вроде как даже есть обходное решение. Проверю и напишу. https://bugs.python.org/issue36468

Comment: @insolor, смог зайти через friGate на сайт, к сожалению решение на нём ничего не сделало. Как были строчки белыми, так и остались.

Comment: Все работает, смотрите ответ.

Comment: @insolor, да, вы правы. Но! Это работает только с тем примером, который есть в вопросе. Но там изменяется цвет текста, а задний фон никак не меняется. И это происходит только в моём примере. Есть идеи как исправить?

Comment: @insolor, заметил что проблема только с задним фоном. Передний абсолютно спокойно меняет свой цвет. Задний фон(background) вообще не меняет цвет. Он всегда остаётся белым

Comment: В вопросе шла речь про изменение фона строки. Если вам нужно менять задний фон целиком - то это уже другой вопрос. На вопрос заданный здесь вопрос я вам ответил.

Comment: @insolor, я и говорю про задний фон строки(background) он у вас в коде и написан

Comment: У меня все работает, я не понимаю о чем вы говорите. Буквально: я не понимаю то что вы пишете выше моего предыдущего комментария.

Comment: @insolor, ваш код не работает, если применить его ко второму уровню Treeview(то есть если к одной строке присвоить другую строку, которая открывается при двойном клике), но если в tag_configure background заменить на foreground, то всё работает

Comment: Уже лучше, но если вы еще покажете пример кода (где-то отдельно, типа pastebin), тогда возможно будет понятнее.

Comment: @insolor, добавил минимально рабочий код. Код добавления строк отдельно, т.к. добавление происходит при нажатии на кнопку

Comment: @insolor, добавил полный код, но к сожалению БД создаётся вручную, поэтому придётся помучиться. Извините, но pastebin'ом не пользуюсь, да и не умею, потому всё в вопросе

Comment: Это уже другой вопрос. Задайте его отдельно.

Comment: @insolor, завтра я приму ваш ответ как правильный. Но я никак не могу понять, почему у вас всё замечательно работает, а у меня никак не хочет пахать, хотя всё очень схоже( отличия минимальны).

Comment: @insolor, создал второй вопрос. Если сможете помочь, то вот ссылка: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1083198/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8f%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%86%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-treeview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Цвет в `Treeview` назначается по тегу элемента. То есть нужно сначала определить, что у элементов, например, с тегом `red` должен быть красный цвет, а у элементов с тегом `green` - зеленый. При этом самим элементам теги нужно назначать при вставке, и изменять при изменении элемента.

Для удобства можно создать класс-наследник `Treeview`, и в нем переопределить методы `insert` и `item`.

**Обновление 15.02.2020:** подсветка строк не работала на Python 3.8, добавил workaround отсюда: https://bugs.python.org/issue36468

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk


class MyTree(ttk.Treeview):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # Элементам с тегом green назначить зеленый фон, элементам с тегом red назначить красный фон
        self.tag_configure('green', background='green')
        self.tag_configure('red', background='red')
        self.tag_configure('yellow', background='yellow')

    def insert(self, parent_node, index, **kwargs):
        '''Назначение тега при добавлении элемента в дерево'''

        item = super().insert(parent_node, index, **kwargs)

        values = kwargs.get('values', None)

        if values:
            if values[2]=="Сдана":
                super().item(item, tag='green')
            elif values[2]=="Просрочена":
                super().item(item, tag='red')
            elif values[2]=="На руках":
                super().item(item, tag='yellow')

        return item


root = tk.Tk()

# Решение проблемы с подсветкой строк на Python 3.8
# Взято отсюда: https://bugs.python.org/issue36468
def fixed_map(option):
    return [elm for elm in style.map('Treeview', query_opt=option) if elm[:2] != ('!disabled', '!selected')]


style = ttk.Style()
style.map('Treeview', foreground=fixed_map('foreground'), background=fixed_map('background'))

columns = ("Tree", "Название", "Автор", "Статус")
tree = MyTree(root, columns=columns[1:])
tree.pack()

for i, heading in enumerate(columns):
    tree.heading('#'+str(i), text=heading)

root_item = tree.insert('', tk.END, text="root", open=True)

tree.insert(root_item, tk.END, text="Книга 1", values=('Капитанская дочка', 'Пушкин', 'На руках'))
tree.insert(root_item, tk.END, text="Книга 2", values=('Книга 2', 'Автор 2', 'Просрочена'))
tree.insert(root_item, tk.END, text="Книга 3", values=('Книга 3', 'Автор 2', 'Сдана'))

root.mainloop()
```

[image: Книги]

Скриншот под Windows 10, Python 3.8.1

[image: Скриншот 3]

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103804/discussion-on-answer-by-insolor-----treeview--).