# Почему не меняется цвет строки в Treeview?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, treeview, python-3.8

Знаю что схожий вопрос задавал ранее ([ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1074824/1365)), но тут другая проблема. Мне дали ответ как можно изменять цвет строки в Treeview и он работает.

### Вот сам пример:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk

root = tkinter.Tk ()

class MyTree(ttk.Treeview):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # Элементам с тегом green назначить зеленый фон, элементам с тегом red назначить красный фон
        self.tag_configure('A', background='green')
        self.tag_configure('B', background='red')
        self.tag_configure('C', background='yellow')

    def insert(self, parent_node, index, **kwargs):
        '''Назначение тега при добавлении элемента в дерево'''

        item = super().insert(parent_node, index, **kwargs)

        values = kwargs.get('values', None)

        if values:
            if values[0]=='BGH':
                super().item(item, tag='A')
            elif values[0]=='HBG':
                super().item(item, tag='B')
            elif values[0]=='GHB':
                super().item(item, tag='C')

        return item

def fixed_map(option):
    return [elm for elm in style.map('Treeview', query_opt=option) if
      elm[:2] != ('!disabled', '!selected')]

style = ttk.Style()
style.map('Treeview', foreground=fixed_map('foreground'),
  background=fixed_map('background'))
style = ttk.Style (root)
style.configure ("Treeview", background="grey", fieldbackground="green")
tree = MyTree (root, columns=('Data','TRu'))
tree.heading ('#0', text='Item')
tree.heading ('#1', text='Data')
tree.heading ('#2', text='TRu')
tree.insert ("", "end", text="Item_0", values=('GHB','100'))
tree.insert ("", "end", text="Item_1", values=('BGH','200'))
lvl1 = tree.insert ("", "end", text="Item_2", values=('HBG','300'))
tree.insert (lvl1, "end", text="Item_0", values=('BGH','100'))
tree.pack ()
root.mainloop ()
```

В нем всё работает замечательно, но если я пробую использовать всё тоже самое, но только с БД sqlite3 и автоматическим выводом инфы из неё, то всё перестаёт работать.

### Вот мой пример:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import sys
import sqlite3
import os

class MyTree(ttk.Treeview):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # Элементам с тегом green назначить зеленый фон, элементам с тегом red назначить красный фон
        self.tag_configure('green', background='green')
        self.tag_configure('red', background='red')
        self.tag_configure('yellow', background='yellow')

    def insert(self, parent_node, index, **kwargs):
        '''Назначение тега при добавлении элемента в дерево'''

        item = super().insert(parent_node, index, **kwargs)

        values = kwargs.get('values', None)

        if values:
            if values[1]=="Сдана":
                super().item(item, tag='green')
            elif values[1]=="Просрочена":
                super().item(item, tag='red')
            elif values[1]=="На руках":
                super().item(item, tag='yellow')

        return item

class Main(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self,*args, **kwargs)
        self.title("Электронный читательский билет - Добавить книги в ЧБ") 
        #Заголовок
        self.geometry("1000x450+300+200")#Размер
        self.resizable(False, False)#Изменение размера окна
        self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", lambda: sys.exit())

        self.s = ttk.Style(self)#Использование темы
        self.s.theme_use('clam')
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.frame.configure(background='gray60',width=1000,height=350)
        self.frame.pack()

        def fixed_map(option):
            return [elm for elm in style.map('Treeview', query_opt=option) if elm[:2] != ('!disabled', '!selected')]

        style = ttk.Style()
        style.map('Treeview', foreground=fixed_map('foreground'), background=fixed_map('background'))

        ttk.Style().configure("Treeview",fieldbackground="royalblue3")

        #Таблица
        self.table = MyTree(self.frame, columns=('DB','Class','litera','adr','phone'), height=16)
        self.table.column('#0', width=210, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.table.column('DB', width=210, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.table.column('Class', width=150, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.table.column('litera', width=30, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.table.column('phone', width=150, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.table.column('adr', width=230, anchor=tk.CENTER)

        self.table.heading('#0', text='ФИО / Книга')
        self.table.heading('DB', text='День рождения / Автор')
        self.table.heading('Class', text='Класс / Статус')
        self.table.heading('litera', text='Литера')
        self.table.heading('phone', text='Телефон')
        self.table.heading('adr', text='Адрес')

        self.table.pack(side='left') 

        self.scroll = ttk.Scrollbar(self.frame, orient='vertical', command=self.table.yview)
        self.scroll.pack(side='right',fill='y')

        conn = sqlite3.connect(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))+"/LC.db")
        cur = conn.cursor()

        #Вывод всех учеников
        cur.execute("SELECT * FROM STUD")
        rows = cur.fetchall()
        for row in rows:
            lvl1 = self.table.insert("" , tk.END ,text=row[0], values=row[1:])
            row1 = row[0],row[1],row[5]
            cur.execute('SELECT BOOK, AUT, STAT FROM LC WHERE FIO=(?) and DB=(?) AND PHONE = (?)',row1)
            books = cur.fetchall()
            for book in books:
                self.table.insert(lvl1, tk.END,text=book[0],values=book[1:])#По задумке тут должен меняться цвет(тут есть значения 'Сдана', 'На руках', 'Просрочена') 


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Main()
    app.mainloop()
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что же не так в моём коде и почему не меняется цвет строки

---

PS Простите что нету самой БД, но там хранится личная информация.

Comment: ваш код не смог запустить на python 3.6.9
на 19-й строке  " item = super().insert(parent_node, index, **kwargs)"
выдает "IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level"

Comment: @Assur, в версии Python 3.6.9 еще не было проблемы с выделением строк в Treeview tkinter, она появилась с версии 3.7.3 . Я до этого задавал походий вопрос и мне дали ответ на него в виде первого кода аказанного в вопросе. Если использовать python 3.8.1, то первый код заработает, но со вторым проблема.

Comment: @user355827, sqlite тут вообще ни при чем. Если его выбросить, и добавить тестовые данные, то строки нормально подсвечиваются под Windows на Python 3.6 и не подсвечиваются на Python 3.8. Вот пример без базы: https://pastebin.com/FMvZVAry

Comment: @DGDays, простое решение: убрать строку `self.s.theme_use('clam')`, тогда все нормально подсвечивается на Python 3.8.

Comment: @insolor, мне не нравится дэфолтная шапка у Treeview, можно тогда только её как-нибудь изменить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подсветка работает с темой по-умолчанию, и не работает, если тему заменить на clam.

Чтобы понять в чем проблема, нужно подробнее разобраться с функцией `fixed_map` (функция изначально взята из [сообщения](https://bugs.python.org/msg342678) в обсуждении на багтрекере python https://bugs.python.org/issue36468):

```
def fixed_map(option):
    return [elm for elm in style.map('Treeview', query_opt=option) if elm[:2] != ('!disabled', '!selected')]
```

Здесь берется список параметров темы (в нашем случае - параметры цвета фона и шрифта элементов `Treeview`), и убираются те элементы списка, в которых первые два элемента равны `'!disabled'` и `'!selected'`.

Модифицируем функцию таким образом, чтобы видеть, что приходит на вход, и что получается на выходе:

```
def fixed_map(option):
    print(option)
    style_map = style.map('Treeview', query_opt=option)
    print('До изменений:', style_map)
    result = [elm for elm in style_map if elm[:2] != ('!disabled', '!selected')]
    print('После изменений:', result)
    return result
```

Закомментриуем изменение темы (`self.s.theme_use('clam')`), запускаем, получаем :

```
foreground
До изменений: [('disabled', 'SystemGrayText'), ('!disabled', '!selected', 'SystemWindowText'), ('selected', 'SystemHighlightText')]
После изменений: [('disabled', 'SystemGrayText'), ('selected', 'SystemHighlightText')]
background
До изменений: [('disabled', 'SystemButtonFace'), ('!disabled', '!selected', 'SystemWindow'), ('selected', 'SystemHighlight')]
После изменений: [('disabled', 'SystemButtonFace'), ('selected', 'SystemHighlight')]
```

Выводится то что и ожидалось, и строки в таблице подсвечиваются нормально. Раскомментируем изменение темы, запускаем еще раз, получаем такой вывод:

```
foreground
До изменений: [('disabled', '#999999'), ('!disabled', '!selected', 'black'), ('selected', '#ffffff')]
После изменений: [('disabled', '#999999'), ('selected', '#ffffff')]
background
До изменений: [('disabled', '#dcdad5'), ('!disabled !selected', '#ffffff'), ('selected', '#4a6984')]
После изменений: [('disabled', '#dcdad5'), ('!disabled !selected', '#ffffff'), ('selected', '#4a6984')]
```

Видим, что параметры фона заданы не так как мы ожидали: вместо двух отдельных элементов `('!disabled', '!selected')` присутствует одна цельная строка `'!disabled !selected'`, из-за этого параметр не удаляется.

Соответственно, чтобы с измененной темой подсветка работала, нужно модифицировать эту функцию таким образом:

```
def fixed_map(option):
    return [elm for elm in style.map('Treeview', query_opt=option)
            if elm[:2] != ('!disabled', '!selected') and elm[0] != '!disabled !selected']
```

Возможны какие-то еще сюрпризы, например параметры `'!disabled'` и `'!selected'` могут идти в другом порядке, при этом могут быть заданы одной строкой, или отдельно, тогда придется использовать более хитрое условие (элемент будет пропущен и если будет присутствовать только один из этих параметров):

```
def fixed_map(option):
    return [elm for elm in style.map('Treeview', query_opt=option)
            if not ({'!disabled', '!selected'} & set(' '.join(elm).split()))]
```

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо! Выручили)